# can anyone explain the use of this in example below?

Tags: javascript, function

```
"use strict"
var avg = function(...n){
   let tot = 0;
   for(let i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
      tot = tot + n[i];
   }

   return tot/n.length;
};

var spice = function(fn, ...n){
   return function(...m){
      return fn.apply(this,n.concat(m));
   }
};

var doAvg = spice(avg, 1,2,3);
console.log(doAvg(4,5,6)); // result is 3.5
```

I don't understand the use of this in line 11. what does this denote here? And why can't we call the function like `fn(n.concat(m))`? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: it keeps the `this` context in case you use `spice` together with functions that depend on `this`. In the example you have given, it could be replaced with `fn(...n.concat(m))` (because `avg` does not do anything with `this`).

Comment: `avg` expects an arguments of numbers, if you just did concat your sending an array.  `apply` will send the array as arguments.

Comment: So i cannot use fn(n.concat(m)). Is ... a must?

Answer (score 1):

[Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
It accepts a single array of arguments.
As shown in the example below with Math.max, instead of:

```
    Math.min(1,2,3,4,5) // which is 1
```

With 'apply' it can be:

```
    Math.min.apply(null,[1,2,3,4,5,...])//in case the length of the list varies
```

The advantage is that, in the example of min, if the length of input is not fixed, then it is more concise to use the apply with an array of input rather than with a list of arguments.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> why cant we call the function like `fn(n.concat(m))` ?

Cause then it would pass *one* argument containing an array. So

```
spice(a, 1,2,3)(4,5,6)
```

would be the same as:

```
a([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

But with using apply, the array gets turned into a list of arguments, so it behaves like:

```
a(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

So a more modern approach of the apply thing would be:

```
fn(...n, ...m)
```

But the author is still using `apply` as it also takes a *context* parameter, were the current context (`this`) gets passed, without `apply` the context would be `window` here:

```
const obj = {
  method: spice(function() {
    console.log(this); // correctly refers to obj
  }
};

obj.method();
```

Comment: But it isnt absolutely necessary to use .apply here right, coz we arent doing anything with the this operator?

Comment: @ashok yes, exactly. But it might get used elsewhere, were the context is important